# loadShape fails for svgs in processing Android mode

Tags: android, processing

I'm working on a live wallpaper app for android in processing.

When I use `loadShape` with some `SVGs` it's not rendering properly in Android mode.
But it's getting rendered correctly in the java mode.

This is one such svg
[kiwi.svg](https://www.svgrepo.com/show/130263/kiwi.svg). It's being rendered like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29627898/61630364-21504200-aca5-11e9-9179-790727711140.png).

But [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1563699329/ogears.png) svg is getting rendered **correctly**.
[Download orange.svg](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1563699329/ogears.svg)

I've put together this simple code that demos what I mean.

```java
PShape svg;
int num = 1;

String[] assets = {
  "tomato.svg", "ogears.svg", "watermelon.svg", "kiwi.svg"
};

void settings() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight, P3D);
}

void setup(){
  svg = loadShape(assets[num]);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  push();
  translate(svg.width/2, svg.height/2);
  scale(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, 1));
  translate(-svg.width/2, -svg.height/2);
  ellipse(displayWidth/2, displayHeight/2, 200, 200);
  //translate(displayWidth/2, displayHeight/2);
  shape(svg);

  push();
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(10);
  rect(0, 0, svg.width, svg.height);
  pop();

  pop();
}

void push(){
  pushMatrix();
  pushStyle();
}

void pop(){
  popStyle();
  popMatrix();
}

void mousePressed(){
  num++;
  num = num % 4;
  svg = loadShape(assets[num]);
}
```

The assets along with the complete code can be found here. [SVGTests.zip](https://github.com/phanirithvij/knowledge/files/3417163/SVGTests.zip)

And it is **not** working even when I use the P2D renderer like `size(.., .., P2D)`.

I'm guessing my svg is not compatible with processing-android.

And when I use [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1563796760/kiwi2.png) svg I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 145` and the sketch dies. [Download-it](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1563796760/kiwi2.svg)

So my question is should I go and replace all my `loadShape` usages with `loadImage` and convert all my svgs to png format instead of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question:

So I've noticed the difference between these two svgs [the working one](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1563699329/ogears.svg) and [the distorted one](https://www.svgrepo.com/show/130263/kiwi.svg).

The differences were

1. The working svg had only `<path>` elements in it.
2. The non-working svg had `<path>` and `<circle>` elements.

The Android-mode renderer is not able to render `<circle>` svg tag properly.

This is how it rendered an svg.

[image: kiwi]

It is to be noted that only the circles are out of shape (not where they're supposed to be).

So I tried converting all of the shapes to `<path>`s using Inkscape. And it seems to be working as the renderer can render `<path>` tags correctly.

Steps to do it:

- Open the svg in Inkscape. Make a backup of the older version if it's needed, this is irreversible.
- <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> select the whole svg
- `Path > Object To Path` <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+C</kbd>
- Save the file now.
- Try again with the new file.

---

**Performance:**

I also observed that the time taken by `loadShape` increased significantly after converting all the `circles` to `paths` in both the java and android modes.

Java renderer (Windows 10 pc)

```java
name: kiwi-paths size: 917.71655 917.71655
time: 178.0 ms
name: kiwi-original size: 917.71655 917.71655
time: 74.0 ms
```

Android renderer (Android 7.0 Redmi note 4)

```java
name: kiwi-paths size: 917.71655 917.71655
time: 190.0 ms
name: kiwi-original size: 917.71655 917.71655
time: 100.0 ms
```

So it's better to **not** have paths but have primitive shapes if running on PC.

And I've also filed an [issue](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/542) at the processing-android github repo.